# SSRS Report RDL is not updating in the Dynamics CRM

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, ssrs-tablix

I have a strange issue..., I was not able to see any updates made to my SSRS Report RDL in the Dynamics CRM, no luck even after changing the parameters and changing the details available in the report table.

After this when deployed to Dynamics CRM, it still shows me the old report, however this does open in my local in visual studio with the appropriate changes made...I am on Dynamics 365 9.0 version online.

Please let me know if there is any hack or trick to overcome this...I am struggling from last one day...couldn't find any proper fix for this online...

Kindly suggest....

Answer (score 0):

Followed the below steps to solve the issue...posting here as it could help someone searching for this...
1.are you sure you are uploading the correct RDL file
2. Clean the VS Solution
3. Reload the project
4. Then rebuild the project in release mode, take the RDL from the release folder.
5. Delete the existing report and reload the one from Release folder and that's it.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. I encountered this problem several years ago. Although I had forgotten the steps I took, I recall having to do a lot to get the RDL to upload. It's good to have the steps recorded here!